# Is it advisable to always use volatile variables with synchronized blocks/methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

As I understand it, `volatile` helps in memory visibility and `synchronized` helps in achieving execution control. `Volatile` just guarantees that the value read by the thread would have the latest value written to it.

Consider the following:

```
public class Singleton{
    private static volatile Singleton INSTANCE = null;

    private Singleton(){}

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(INSTANCE==null){
             synchronized(Integer.class){
                 if(INSTANCE==null){
                     INSTANCE = new Singleton();
                 }
             }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

In the above piece of code, we use double-checked locking. This helps us create only one instance of Singleton and this is `communicated` to the other threads by the creating thread as soon as possible. This is what the keyword `volatile` does. We need the above `synchronized block` because the delay in the thread reading the `INSTANCE` variable as null and initializing the object could cause a `race condition`.

Now consider the following:

```
public class Singleton{
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = null;

    private Singleton(){}

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(){
        if(INSTANCE==null){
             INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Say we have 2 threads `t1` and `t2` trying to get the `Singleton` object. Thread `t1` enters the `getInstance()` method first and creates the `INSTANCE` object. Now this newly created object should be visible to all the other threads. If the `INSTANCE` variable is not `volatile` then how do we make sure that the object is still not in `t1's` memory and visible to other threads. How soon is the above `INSTANCE` initialized by `t1` visible to other threads ?

Does this mean that it is advisable to always make variables volatile with synchronized ?
In what scenarios would we not require the variable to be volatile ?

P.S I have read other questions on StackOverflow but could not find the answer to my question. Please comment before down-voting.

My question arises from the explanation given [here](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html)

Comment: Did you really mean to make the variable public? That's a mistake to start with - it should only be accessed via the method. At that point, there's no need for it to be volatile in the latter case, as synchronization already involves a memory barrier.

Comment: @JonSkeet Meant to make it private. Thanks for bringing that up. So when you say it involves a memory barrier, does it mean that it should be flushed to the main memory as soon as it creates the instance variable ?

Comment: It doesn't *create* the INSTANCE variable - it *writes* to it. But no, it means that unlocking the monitor introduces a memory barrier. I'm writing up an answer.

Comment: @NthPortal: Sorry, I should have been more precise - you're right, the JLS doesn't even use the term "memory barrier". Hopefully the answer is more accurate than the comment :)

Comment: @NthPortal: Although I'd say that it doesn't need to be the same synchronized block - just a synchronized block locking the same monitor :)

Comment: My previous comment was wrong, and you are quite correct @JonSkeet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're missing is this from [JLS 17.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

> An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

Which is very similar to the bullet about volatile variables:

> A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

Then in 17.4.5:

> If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).

... where hb is the "happens-before" relation.

Then:

> If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.

The memory model is incredibly complicated and I don't claim to be an expert, but my understanding is that the implication of the quoted parts is that the second pattern you've shown is safe without the variable being volatile - and indeed any variable which is *only* modified and read within synchronization blocks for the same monitor is safe without being volatile. The more interesting aspect (to me) is what happens to the variables within the object that the variable's value refers to. If `Singleton` isn't immutable, you've still potentially got problems there - but that's one step removed.

To put it more concretely, if two threads call `getInstance()` when `INSTANCE` is null, one of those threads will lock the monitor first. The write action of a non-null reference to `INSTANCE` happens-before the unlock operation, and that unlock operation happens-before the lock operation of the other thread. The lock operation happens-before the read of the `INSTANCE` variable, therefore the write happens-before the read... at which point, we are guaranteed that the write is visible to the reading thread.

Comment: To me, those quotes from the JLS are not clear that caches are flushed to main memory when exiting a monitor, and reread from memory when entering a monitor. However, Brian Goetz is quite explicit about it [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/). I apologize for my error. I am going to delete my previous comment(s), however, as they are entirely incorrect, and I don't want to generate any confusion.

Comment: @NthPortal: The JLS deliberately doesn't talk about caches (except in a very *few* places, not including volatile variables - and even in those places, I view it as a mistake) - that's not the only way in which memory ordering is relevant, as there's also JIT reordering etc. The JLS talks about observable results, which is all that's important. It's up to the JVM to make sure that the JLS is obeyed.

Answer (score -2):

This explanation of what is happening here is entirely wrong, as I misunderstood the Java Memory Model. See [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34149999/5101123).

#### Safe lazy initialization

The action you are attempting in this case is "lazy-initialization", and that particular pattern is useful for instances, but sub-optimal for static variables. For static variables, the *lazy initialization holder class idiom* is preferred.

The following quote and code block are copied directly from Item 71 of *Effective Java (2nd Edition)*, by Josh Bloch:

> Because there is no locking if the field is already initialized, it
>   is critical that the field be declared volatile.

```
// Double-check idiom for lazy initialization of instance fields
private volatile FieldType field;
FieldType getField() {
    FieldType result = field;
    if (result == null) { // First check (no locking)
        synchronized(this) {
            result = field;
            if (result == null) // Second check (with locking)
                field = result = computeFieldValue();
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

In one of his talks, he recommended to copy this structure *exactly* when performing lazy initialization for instance fields, as it is optimal in such situations, and it is very easy to break it by changing it.

#### What is actually happening?

EDIT: This section is incorrect.

The `volatile` keyword means that all read and write operations for the variable are atomic; that is, they happen as one single step from the perspective of anything else. Additionally, `volatile` variables are always read from and written to main memory, **not** processor cache. The combination of these two properties guarantees that, as soon as a volatile variable variable is modified on one thread, subsequent reads on another thread will read the updated value. This guarantee is **not** present for non-`volatile` variables.

The double-check idiom does not guarantee that only one instance is created. Rather, it is so that, once the variable is initialized, future calls to `getInstance()` do not need to enter a `synchronized` block, which is expensive.

The guarantee that it is not initialized twice is made by the fact that (a) it is a volatile field, and (b) it is checked (again) *inside* of the `synchronized` block. The outer check helps efficiency; the inner check guarantees single initialization.

I highly recommend reading Item 71 of *Effective Java (2nd Edition)* for a more complete explanation. I also recommend the book in general as being fantastic.

UPDATE:

The local `result` variable used reduces the number of accesses of the `volatile` field needed, which improves performance. If the local variable was left out, and all reads and writes directly accessed the `volatile` field, it should have the same result, but take slightly longer.

Comment: Can you explain the significance of the `result` variable in your example ? How is it different from the example I mentioned ?

Comment: Regarding your Update on volatile, doesn't your comment "... Updates to non-volatile variables within a synchronized block are not guaranteed to propagate to other threads before they enter the same synchronized block." mean that say if thread `t1` reads `result` as `null` and enters the synchronized block, it reads `result` as `null` again and initializes the `field`. In the mean time, thread `t2` reads `result` as `null` and enters the synchronized block. But this time as the thread `t2` enters the same synchronized block, the value of `result` should be propagated right ?

Comment: Not necessarily. There is no guarantee about how long it takes for the cache of one processor to propagate to the cache of another, to my knowledge.

Comment: I am confused. So you still believe we need the `volatile` in method 2 ? I thought your comment meant that `t2` would get the `INSTANCE` as soon as it entered the same synchronized block.

Comment: From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html: *An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that monitor.*. So the second example in the question is completely safe: the write to the instance in the synchronized block is guaranteed to happen before subsequent reads in the same block.

Comment: You appear to have ignored the happens-before relation quoted in my answer. The second example *is* safe.

Comment: @Viraj If `INSTANCE` is not `volatile`, then when `t2` enters the `synchronized` block after `t1` has left it, `t2` may read the old `null` value of `INSTANCE`, rather than the new value. The new value may still be in the cache for `t1`, and has not yet made it to `t2`'s cache.

Comment: @NthPortal that's wrong. Read Jon's answer, quoting the JLS, and my comment, quoting the java.util.concurrent package documentation.

Comment: @JonSkeet The `synchronized` block for one thread happens before the `synchronized` block of the other, and consequently, the write of `INSTANCE` in `t1` happens before the read of `INSTANCE` in `t2`. However, that should better be stated as "The write to `t1`'s cache happens before the read from `t2`'s cache;" they may be different values.

Comment: @NthPortal wrong. Again. Read the javadoc: Chapter 17 of The Java™ Language Specification defines the happens-before relation on memory operations such as reads and writes of shared variables. The results of a write by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to a read by another thread only if the write operation happens-before the read operation.

Comment: @NthPortal: No, that's just not true: "If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second." In this case, the write happens-before the read, therefore the write is visible to and ordered before the read, therefore they won't have different values.

Comment: @JBNizet You are correct, though the it was not clear to me from the JLS that caches are flushed/invalidated when leaving/entering monitors.